# Drush error on core update "corrupt (wrong md5 checksum)"

Tags: drush, updating, security

I'm getting this error when I try to update core with Drush:

```
File drupal-7.41.tar.gz is corrupt (wrong md5 checksum).  [error]
Updating project drupal failed. Attempting to roll back to previously
installed version.   [error]
```

I've tried to refresh and clear all the caches I can think of (`drush rf`, `drush cc all`, `drush cc drush`) but the error continues.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at this drupal issue queue thread, https://www.drupal.org/node/1961304 , if you are using Drush Make and having problems try `--no-cache` option for your build.

Otherwise assure the downloaded Drupal version, or module, is readable by the Drush user. If drush cannot read the file then the md5 checksum cannot be run and Drush will report a corrupt file:

> @sobi3ch: this appears to be a permissions issue. If i'm reading the
>   Drush output correctly,
>   "md5_file(/var/www/vhosts/etcc.pl/drupal-7.38.tar.gz): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied" is saying the md5 checksum function is
>   unable to open the file to validate the checksum on it, which causes
>   drush to think the file has the wrong checksum.

Comment: We found the permission issue at the same time. Marking this as the answer.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else finds this answer unsatisfactory, try passing the undocumented `--no-md5` flag to `drush up`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the error seems to be a bit of a red herring as it seems to have been a directory permissions issue. I moved the site to a new directory recently and one of the parent folders was not writable. Changing that has fixed this issue for me.